# How to give WooCommerce paid customer random url to hidden website

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce-subscriptions, woocommerce-memberships

This is my problem. I have a pdf document which I want to send/download if a customer has paid on my Woocommerce site. But this customer can share this document with others so I have a revenue loss.

Other option: after the customer paid I give them access to a special (membership) page. But they have to login in etc. not good customer experience, because they use this document once.

Is their a plugin, that after a customer paid a random url is created and the can acces this url for a certain time? So the data cannot be shared?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Have you checked the built in WooCommerce for this? like with limit on number of downloads and so on: https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/digital-downloadable-product-handling/
And when it comes to documents or PDF files, the users can share them either way. But I think this is the most simple way todo it

Comment: thanks for your reply, that's why I want to add the content of the pdf on a webpage instead of delivering a PDF. But a webpage they can still share the url. So if there is an option to make random url and to have an option to make this url active for e.g. 24 hours then my problem is solved

Comment: They still can share url even for 24 hours... And customers are logged in anyway so i dont see what is the problem there. If visitor is logged out he will need to login eitherway.  You dont need membership if you can code. What i would to is to create page template check if current user is logged or not (ask for login) then check if current user has purchased this product then show content else 404 page ;)